# Connection id application never completed

Tags: .net-core, middleware

I am having very rare issue with my .net core application. Only place where its mentioned is here
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11025

I have checked my code and don't see any problematic middlewares, although some of them are extensions from other libs, and my next step is to check those.

App is hosted in Kubernetes in cloud, and behavior is that specific connection gets corrupted in a way that app is not accepting new requests on that connection for 1-2 mins, and than I get Critical error with message **Connection id "" application never completed**

Anyone had any experience with this error?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: No, but it is problem with midlewares. Focus on that. It can be in some lib if you are using it.

Comment: This error happens when Kestrel looses track of a request before removing it from an internal map (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3ea008c80d5cc63de7f90ddfd6823b7b006251ff/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Infrastructure/ConnectionManager.cs).  So basically it means that Kestrel did not clean up the request properly.  It is _very_ hard to see how middleware could be responsible for this.